# onclick not calling my javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I am trying to call a javascript function from an onclick, but it does not seem to be registering. I am having trouble tracking down the issue because no error is being reported in chrome inspect element.

MY button code looks like this:

```
$button = "<button class=\"btn btn-mini btn-success\" id = \"$divName\" onClick\"return upVote($linkID, $linkUser)\">$votes Votes</button>";
```

and my java script looks like this:

```
function upVote(id, userID)
    {


        alert(id);




        return false;
    }
```

you can try out the buttons on the blog link tab on this page:

http://www.beerportfolio.com/beerPage2.php?id=f5DoHi

Comment: You're missing `=` after `onclick`.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using inline javascript event handlers?

Comment: I think you just missed the = sign. onClick="return upVote..."

Comment: I made a small mistake and now everyone down votes me, got to love stack lol

Comment: upvoted. i don't see why this deserves downvotes. mike described the problem clearly, showed his code, and even included a link to the site itself. doesn't matter that the problem was a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the "=" in

```
onClick=\"return upVote($linkID, $linkUser)\"
```

Comment: and that's when you know its time for me to go to bed... thanks lol

Comment: Hahaha, don't worry, it happens :P

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use onClick. Second, write it like so: `onclick="upVote(1,2)"`

Comment: whats wrong with on click?

Comment: It mixes presentation with functionality.